# iOS 9 Swift 2.0 UITextFieldDidChange

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am having a problem using the `textFieldDidChange` or `textFieldDidEndEditing` method in a subclass of `UITextField`. I change the `UITextField`'s `text` property in another source (object). Can this method be called?

Answer (score 4):

you can use the below coding and you can follow blow description

UITextField and dragging the "Editing Changed" send event to your subclass unit.

[image: UITextField Change Event]

or you can use the delegate method

```
func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool
```

or progrmatically

```
 yourtextField.addTarget(self, action: "textFieldDidChange:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingChanged)

func textFieldDidChange(textField: UITextField) 
{
  //your code
}
```

or the Notification is available in `Swift 2.0`

```
  let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
 notificationCenter.addObserver(
self,
selector: "textFieldTextChanged:",
name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification,
object: nil
 )

 func textFieldTextChanged(sender : AnyObject) {
   // do your stuff here
 }
```

the notification Type as

> public let UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification: String
>    public let UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification: String
>     public let UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification: String

for more information use this [link](https://www.codefellows.org/blog/how-to-implement-an-nsnotification-observer-in-swift)

Comment: I need to have `textFieldDidChange` or `textFieldDidEndEditing` called when I change the `UITextField`'s value from another object. Can that be done?

Comment: in that same class  you can use ** textFieldDidEndEditing** , if you are another object send the observer you can use the ** UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification** for